# Bad Result when Merging Rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I'm trying to merge 9 raster files I have. for some reason. if I merge a few of them it works, especially when they are close to each other. But whenever I try to merge all of them, together I get this bad result:
[image]

I assume that maybe it has to do with the fact that some of the rasters are very far from each other geographicaly but I don't know if it has to do with that.

My end goal is to merge all the 9 rasters into one raster layer.

Comment: While undesirable, it appears to be the *correct* result, which means the issue is not the process, but the data.

Comment: Do your rasters overlap in that place so that one or another source image does have data over that black area?

Comment: No overlap, I think one raster is problematic because I  can merge all of them beside one that also located in wrong place